# Permalinks and jQuery Error in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need help with reloading some part of page, actualy i want to make reload some content (post) on my wordpress blog without reloading page.. simple users can click on refresh button and get new post ...

Im make random.php file and im include in my page this file, so there is 6 random posts...

So now i need reload this part on click without reloading all page, im try found solution on the google but cant find any good tutorial or

My code:
http://pastebin.com/nf6kzEZS

So all this works very fine if i have Permalinks on Default (`http://localhost/wordpress/?p=123`)

But when i change Permalink script cant load random.php files, im try change extension to random.html and works but i need to load php..

So where can be problems.. im also try on localhost without any plugins and same...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not including jQuery like it should: using [`enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Second, the problem you are encounter is related to relative paths. Because you have `random.php` in root (localhost/random.php), when you are into another page, localhost/post/date/random.php will be... not found. Make sense? :)

Now, what i'm doing is this: in `header.php` i define a javascript variable (BEFORE including any custom script!), let's say sitepath :

```
<script>
var SITE_PATH = '<?php echo home_url( '/' ) ?>';
</script>
```

Now, in your script you can do this:

```
$.get(SITE_PATH+'random.php', function(data){ ... });
```

Make sense?

Comment: Im use this only on home page so paths is okey, because when i turn off permalinks all works fine... but with permalinks cant load php files...

Comment: Then install firebug and check the network activity in console. Also, what's the content of random.php?

Comment: When i enable permalinks firebug say 
GET random.php  404 Not Found

But i can access to file http://mysite.com/random.php without any error...

When i disable permalinks firebug say GET random.php Okey

Here is random.php

http://pastebin.com/0daGpDbQ